# Inserting text into an element on another page when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

The user is on the 'prices' page of a website. They see a product they like. They click the button associated with that product. On clicking that button, they are taken to the 'contact us' page and the product code/description of the product they clicked, is inserted into the text-field of a form for them to send an email to the website maker.

Can it be done? How would be the best way to achieve this?

Sorry, I'm still pretty new to web design so I'm at a loss as to where to start...

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: you can use `localStorage` to store and retrieve on any page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yes, that can be done. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can do this with **$_GET**.

Let's say this is your product page:

```
<a href="contact.php?product=milk">Click here to buy milk</a>
<a href="contact.php?product=eggs">Click here to buy eggs</a>
```

Now you can simply insert the product's name using **echo** in your **contact.php** page:

```
<textarea><?php echo $_GET['product']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Is there any good reason not to link to the contact form with the product directly? Why do you need sessions for that?